# README images do not show up on repo main page

Tags: html, github, bitbucket, markdown, readme

I am trying to include images in my readme using the command:

```
<img src="./images/test.jpg" width="200">
```

[But the contents of the image do not show up on the repo main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooAEu.png)

[The image does show up if I click on the README file, however](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVpCL.png)

My images will show up on the main page if I use the markdown command:

```
![][./images/test.jpg]
```

But the images appear extremely large. The only successful way I've found to reduce the image size is with the html command above.

Any solutions to either make the image appear on the main page or reduce the size of an image using the markdown-style command?

Examples are from Bitbucket but I've tested this in GitHub as well. Same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

For Github you could try the direct link.

```
<img src="https://github.com/Repo/raw/main/src/socialcard.png" alt="Alt">
```